# Laravel : I click on logout button and successfully done but when i click on back button

Tags: laravel-5.8

I am not able to flush cache after logout in laravel.

On logout I have done lots things but nothing is working for me . I am not able to find a way in laravel to flush cache on my logout.

```
return redirect(\URL::previous());
return redirect(\URL::previous());
```

also tried Clouser class

Answer (score 0):

This Code might help you.

```
public function logout(Request $request) {
        header("cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header("cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
        Session::flush();
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        Session::flash('succ_message', 'Logged out Successfully');
        return redirect('signin');
    }
```

For more details please click on this [Link](https://www.w3adda.com/blog/laravel-clear-cache-after-logout).